# How to convert DNA sequences in FASTA format to OneHot Encoded Pandas Dataframe for Neural Networks?

Tags: deep-learning, sequence

DNA sequences in FASTA format look like:

```
CATGCATTAGTTATTAATAGTAATCAATTACGGGGTCATTAGTTCA...
```

I am trying to convert them into one-hot encoded data in a Pandas dataframe so that I can use various neural networks to analyze them. This has probably been done many times. Can someone point me to references or Python packages for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about any python package but you can simply do integer encoding using labelencoder() and then do one-hot encoding.

```
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_encoded_seq = label_encoder.fit_transform(seq)    
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
integer_encoded_seq = integer_encoded_seq.reshape(len(integer_encoded_seq), 1)
onehot_encoded_seq = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded_seq)
```

Refer [this](https://www.kaggle.com/thomasnelson/working-with-dna-sequence-data-for-ml).